# Toy vendors in Rome (on the piazza)

Tags: rome

Just kind of a weird question.

I'm in Rome right now, and tomorrow, I will meet with friends with two young kinds (7&9) for the remainder of the week.

I know that at some point they will want to have some of the toys that some street vendor sell (especially the ones that have lights).

I don't expect the toys to last more than a couple of hours.

Is it safe to buy from them (the act of buying)?

---

Edit :

We finally did not buy the toys from the street vendors, there were sold cheaper at the convenient store next to my place.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by safe?

Comment: This question reminds me of a [question about unscrupulous street vendors in Milan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/102371/47309) and another [question about similar unscrupulous hawkers in Paris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13300/47309).

Comment: Does ‘safe’ refer to the act of buying the toys, or the quality of the toys themselves? Maybe you could just say no to the kids when they ask, or have a quiet word with the parents beforehand.

Comment: safe to buy. (will edit the question)

Comment: @Traveller, It might be me of the parents that will buy it, I will not buy it before asking permission

Comment: A street peddler toy will unlikely explode in your face, but may not be the wisest long-term investment... Health-wise, I'd say it's "safe" as long as you don't lick it or put it in your mouth.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you afraid of being scammed, mugged, extorted in any way, whilst being distracted by the sale?

Comment: @undercat LOL, I'm not looking for a long term toy, just something for the boys to play for a couple of hours to spend off some energy.

Comment: @JoErNanO yeah that's what I'm "afraid" of,

Comment: Your fear is more than enough to save you from being assaulted (not particularly likely) or unduly scammed (possible, but then again these toys are in themselves a scam, since in any actual shop there are nicer, non-counterfeited, and perhaps with a lifespan of more than one hour). I'd steer children and parents toward a real toy shop, or a “cartoleria” or at the very least to a Chinese general store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's completely safe according to your definition of safe. I have been to Rome many times and spent lots of time people watching there. Locals and foreigners alike have no issues with their purchases although, as some have mentioned, the products are typically low quality and overpriced.

in my experience the same is true of similar vendors in any city popular with tourists anywhere in the world. I have never heard of the things you are afraid of happening.

Comment: That wasn't specified in the question so I gave a straightforward response to directly answer it. I've now added background context (which was already strongly implied).

Comment: It’s implicit in every question, and “I know what I’m talking about” is, sadly, not implicit in responses on the Internet. Thanks for your edit: you’ve made it clear that you *do* know what you’re talking about and this is now an excellent answer, so +1.

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more careful in the future.